# Query about privileges in oracle

Tags: oracle

How to invoke privileges to create a view in oracle 10g enterprise edition from the user scott? I am getting insufficient privilege error message while trying to create a view for an existing table

Comment: Does the user creating the view own the table they are referencing?

Answer (score 0):

To give privileges to create a view, You need to grant `CREATE VIEW` to Scott user from sysdba user as follows:

```
GRANT CREATE ANY VIEW TO Scott;
-- OR --
GRANT CREATE VIEW TO Scott;
```

Answer (score 0):

TL/DR: you need CREATE VIEW system privilege and SELECT object privilege on the related table.

Actually any user having been granted CREATE VIEW with admin option can grant CREATE VIEW this include SYSDBA and SYSTEM users but also any user having DBA role. To able to create a view on a table you generally also need SELECT privilege on the table.

Example with CREATE VIEW WITH ADMIN OPTION:

```
SQL> --
SQL> show user;
USER is "SYS"
SQL> --
SQL> create user scott identified by "tiger";

User created.

SQL> grant create session to scott;

Grant succeeded.

SQL> --
SQL> create user myadmin identified by "myadmin" quota unlimited on users;

User created.

SQL> grant create session to myadmin;

Grant succeeded.

SQL> grant create table to myadmin;

Grant succeeded.

SQL> grant create view to myadmin with admin option;

Grant succeeded.

SQL> --
SQL> connect myadmin/myadmin
Connected.
SQL> grant create view to scott;

Grant succeeded.

SQL> create table t(x int);

Table created.

SQL> insert into t values(4);

1 row created.

SQL> commit;

Commit complete.

SQL> grant select on t to scott;

Grant succeeded.

SQL> --
SQL> connect scott/tiger
Connected.
SQL> create view v as select * from myadmin.t;

View created.

SQL> select * from v;

     X
----------
     4
```

Comment: Actually the user is scott.  How to grant privilege from scott to scott.  While installatioin in password management i did not uncheck the sys user.  Only scott user is in use.  Other users are not available.  How to switch to sys user. Please help

Comment: You cannot grant privilege from scott to scott: you need another account that has already the required privilege with the admin option: typically a DBA account: it can be sys/sysdba but you need the password for this: get in touch with your DBA.